# How to skip banner message when using ssh inside python subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, banner, skip

I understand that `ssh -t -q` can help to skip banner messages in terms of bash scripting. But how do I skip the banner message while using `subprocess.Popen` to connect the remote machine via ssh? The problem is that the banner message is captured as an error message and it shows as **ERROR [ < banner message> ]**

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh","%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
print "Executed on ", host
if result == [ ] :
        error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
        print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
        print result
    return
```

Comment: have you tried in the same way ? `ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh","-t", "-q","%s" % HOST, COMMAND] ...`

Comment: also, do yourself a favor and use something like fabric or paramiko.

Comment: Hi Lohmar, 

Thanks for the response. I used ssh -t -q inside subprocess. but my commands are not getting executed. Since I am working in a kind of restricted env and access I refrain from using paramiko and fabric.

Comment: Hi Lohmar, 

Thanks for the response. I used ssh -t -q inside subprocess. but my commands are not getting executed. But when I use only -q banners are skipped.I am receiving an output like ERROR[]  below. Since I am working in a kind of restricted env and access I refrain from using paramiko and fabric.


ERROR: []
Skipping Logging on  
Executed  on  
Logging in 
Executed on  
ERROR: []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ' ssh -o LogLevel=error ' to avoid warnings and banners